# Finding midpoint in class interval to calculate mean for cumulative frequency graph.

Tags: statistics

In a cumulative frequency graph (or histogram), the data is often given in class intervals. To calculate the estimated mean of the data, the formula is:

$$\frac{\sum m\cdot f}{\sum f}$$

where $m =$ midpoint of the class intervals and $f =$ frequency.

However, the main point of this question is, **how do I calculate the midpoint of a class interval?**

**Example $1$**

For a class interval of $30 \le x < 35$, the midpoint is $32.5$.

**Example $2$**

For a  class interval of $0.1 \le x \le 0.5$ , the midpoint is $0.25$.

**Example $3$**

$x< 40\dotsc$ $x < 50\dotsc$ the midpoint between the two is $45$.

**Example $4$**

$< 10\dotsc < 20\dotsc < 35$ the midpoint is $4.5$, $14.5$ etc.

Is  there a formula to this or something? I honestly don't get how to calculate the midpoints. Maybe it has something to do with the inequality signs?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The formula for a midpoint of a class interval is the lowest range plus the highest range divided by two. So say you have a class interval of $5-9.9$. You would calculate it this way:

$5+9.9= 14.9/2 = 7.45$ or approximately $7.5$

Answer (score 0):

The formula for calculating mid-points from class intervals or true class interval (both in the same way),  is by adding upper limit to the lower limit and divided by $2$.